# Windows SQL Server Express 2012 and LDAP external server integration

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server, ldap

I have a new installation of Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server Express 2012 with the management tools.

I'm planning to create there a simple synchronization that will make queries twice per day to an external LDAP service (not a Windows active directory server) and fill a table in the local SQL instance. I've seen other questions here about this, and all of them refer to the creation of a Linked Server, but I think that will only work if the remote LDAP service was a Windows AD server.

I'm able to query this server using the LDP tool, but looks like I cannot add it as a linked server. Any ideas?

Comment: What LDAP server are you connecting to?  Perhaps that vendor has an OLEDB provider?

Comment: It's Oracle Corporation; Sun-Directory-Server/11.1.1.5.0. I found some information about how to add it using the provider MSDAORA, but I'm not sure what parameters should I include for making the connection to the linked server...

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to configure this? Or are you not averse to writing some code?

In the latter case, it should be relatively easy to write a small program that connects to both the LDAP server and the database and synchronizes the data. I've written such a thing once in PL/SQL in Oracle -- if it's possible there it should be possible in most languages and environments!

Comment: I want to make a small script that does the ldap synchronization. At first I considered doing it using PowerShell or Perl, but I thought that maybe there was some built-in functionality with Windows SQL Server.